# Does 'how do you like something' ask the state of it or the way of listener's how to dealing with it?

Tags: vocabulary, adverbs

> “**How** do you like your new school?”
>   “I like it very much.”

When I first heard the dialogue, I thought *how* is used to denote *[to what extent](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/how)*, and this draws the answer of *very much*. But there’s none of this kind of usages in the dictionaries. So I got this second thought: (A) *how* denotes *in what way*, and this is matched with the whole answer *I like it very much*.

However it doesn’t explain these words: *“used to ask if something is good, bad, etc - **How do you like** the soup?* ([Webster’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/how)). If this is applied, the *'I like it very much’* would be meaning *I’m on the state of liking it very much* or *it’s very good on me*.

How do I have to understand the *how*?

Comment: The phrase is more ___how do you like__ something_ - "how do you like the weather, how do you like your job, your studies, etc.

Comment: @Listenever Here is my intuition. This *how* is an open question, and a typical response would be similar to those to a *how much do you like* question, but it allows you to add your opinion, e.g. "How do you like it?" "I like it very much, but I wish our football field would be a little bigger." So, basically, it's *to what extent* and *in what way* merged into one, and used for asking for someone's opinion. This is just my intuition, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Collins [how](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/how) its sense 6:

> 6) to what extent, degree, amount, etc.

When you say:

> **How** do you like your new school?

you are really saying:

> **How much** do you like your new school?

The clue is in the response “I like it very much.”